# Node.js local package conditional exports don't work in svelte/vite

Tags: node.js, sveltekit

I inhereted a Sveltekit project that includes a local package.

The structure is like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── localPackages
│   └── firebase-ssr
│       ├── browser
│       │   ├── auth.mjs
│       │   ├── index.mjs
│       │   ├── storage.mjs
│       │   └── store.mjs
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── server
│       │   ├── auth.mjs
│       │   ├── index.mjs
│       │   ├── storage.mjs
│       │   └── store.mjs
│       ├── types.d.ts
│       └── yarn.lock
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.cjs
├── src
│   └── (main project source code)
```

The local package `firebase-ssr` has some conditional exports in the localPackages/firebase-ssr/package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "firebase-ssr",
    "description": "Subpackage to work around dynamic imports and SSR",
    "version": "0.0.3",
    "exports": {
        "node": "./server/index.mjs",
        "browser": "./browser/index.mjs"
    },
    "typings": "types.d.ts",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "firebase": "9.0.1",
        "firebase-admin": "^9.10.0"
    }
}
```

The main project imports the local package in its `devDependencies` inside the main project's ./package.json:

```json
        "firebase-ssr": "file:./localPackages/firebase-ssr",
```

In a .ts file intended for both SSR and client-side rendering, I import from the local package:

```
import { init, Auth, Storage, Store } from 'firebase-ssr';
```

This all seems fine, VS Code understands the import. But when I run `svelte-kit dev` I get the following error:

> The request url "/home/user1/abstraction/localPackages/firebase-ssr/browser/index.mjs" is outside of Vite serving allow list.

This project is deployed and working in production, so I assume I must be missing some sort of configuration in my dev environment. (Unfortunately I can't reach out to the original developer.)

Addendum:
The project uses an old version of Sveltekit, so I updated to the most recent version, and all that happened is that the error changes to

> Failed to load url /localPackages/firebase-ssr/browser/index.mjs (resolved id: /mnt/c/dev/project_foobar/localPackages/firebase-ssr/browser/index.mjs) in /mnt/c/dev/project_foobar/src/lib/firebase.ts. Does the file exist?

I am pretty new to node.js and sveltekit so any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Update 1:

I figured out a little more specific details.

The issue is with a file `firebase.ts` intended to render both on the server and in the client.

The actual import in the source code for `firebase.ts` is this:

```js
import { init, Auth, Storage, Store } from 'firebase-ssr';
```

`localPackages/firebase-ssr` has been installed in `./node_modules` (along with all the not-local packages).

But when I look at the `firebase.ts` file that is actually being served to the browser, it has become:

```js
import {init, Auth, Storage, Store} from "/localPackages/firebase-ssr/browser/index.mjs";
```

This suggests to me that svelete (or vite, I don't know) is resolving the conditional export to the `localPackages/firebase-ssr` directory and not the `node_modules/firebase-ssr` directory. I don't know how to fix that, however.